# Is it normal to have an unsecured copper line coming off a propane tank?

Tags: propane

Due to insurance purposes anything with gas or electricity I pay someone else to do.

This 1000 gallon tank had new copper ran to our new generator.  After they did the job I got to looking at it and it's floppy and loose which leads me to believe it will be very dangerous come Winter with a couple feet of snow pushing it off with a broom daily.

Is this really a typical line install on a tank?

I searched online and I see a lot of flex lines to allow movement....

I'm basically looking for confirmation that this isn't right. Then I need to find a way to get them to change it.

[image: propane tank]

Comment: Where are you in the world ? I have seen worse but normally in my area they have a clamp to secure the pipe at the fitting both lines look like they are flopping with no restraints.

Comment: Vermont, 5 miles from Canada;)

Comment: I am not positive but as long as the pipe is buried deep enough possibly 1 anchor at the tank is all that is required we sleeve the pipes at ground level up ~12” to protect from weed eaters and lawn mowers then the restraint close to the fitting and that is just to keep the pipe from falling over if it is removed like a rubber bungee cord. I always thought that was silly because the only reason to remove the line would be to change the primary regulator.  I don’t think the sleeve into the ground is required because several inspectors have commented that they liked that. But I am in Oregon.

Comment: Thank you! They ran new copper for a new generator install we had.  The old line was straight down and in the ground... never thought anything of it...

Comment: Possibly they ran to the side so they could trench, your first line looks like coated steel. ACR line is ok (copper used in hvac) also but usually more expensive, I have used it when I had part of a roll that had been sitting at atmospheric pressure with no plug (takes forever to get the moisture out).